# send direction to phone

Tags: google-maps, map-directions

I am using  [Google direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to fetch directions for user while driving but on a webpage. I want once user is satisfied with direction I can send this to their phone,car,etc. where they can use google maps to navigate their way through.

Comment: What do you mean by send directions to a phone?  Are you referring to something like the "Send directions to your phone" link in maps.google.com?  If so, why don't you do what they did?

Comment: @Rob yes that's what I meant I tried to look for a plugin that could do that but couldn't find one

Comment: @ChrisIhure did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @SyedAlihassan Not yet.